# Extract method with contract

Tags: code-contracts

In a powerpoint slideshow I saw about code contracts they right click on some code and get the option to "extract method with contract".

But I dont get that option?

How is it possible to extract a method with contract?

Regards

Comment: IDE? Language? Intent?

Comment: Code contracts is C#, so Visual studio

Comment: If it's **C#** you should've put the **C#** tag. The more information you give, the more help you will get.

Comment: I dont get why is downvoted. I wrote "code contracts" which is c#, and the tag "code contract". A person who knows c# and not code contract cant answer that question.

Comment: Microsoft Research were doing something around extracting methods with contracts but I don't think it has actually been released.